# Delete already existing animation

Tags: animation, armature

So, I got a .ABC file and it has an animation already on it. How do I delete this animation?

Comment: Can you delete the keyframes on the objects?

Comment: There are no keyframes. I don't know if that's inherent with a .abc file or what but the object is just moving.

Comment: Could you provide a picture of the setup?

Comment: You can freeze a frame in the modifier. Altering animations of alembic files isn't builtin.

Comment: Open the NLA editor, that will show the animation tracks for all objects. Just select them all and delete - that should remove any sort of animation.

Comment: What is the NLA editor? Is it the "Nonlinear Animation" timeline? because that doesn't have any keyframes in it.